# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() has been deprecated - Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, bluetoothadapter

**I'm having tough time understanding a small thing.**

Upon running my code, I'm getting following error

```dart
C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-6.1.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:152:
warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                                                                  ^
```

It is obvious, I'm getting this error because `BluetoothAdapter` method use in `ServiceManager.java` got deprecated as mentioned in docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getDefaultAdapter()). My compileSdkVersion is 31.

Here is how `isBluetoothServiceEnabled` function looks like in `ServiceManager.java`

```dart
 private boolean isBluetoothServiceEnabled() {
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();

        // --- Solution #1 (Didn't work)
        // val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        // bluetoothManager.getAdapter().isEnabled();
        
        // --- Solution #1 (Didn't work)
        // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
        // bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        // return bluetoothManager;
        // } else {
        // bluetoothManager = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // return bluetoothManager;
        // }
    }
```

Now upon searching on google I found following solutions. Everyone of them is giving error.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894425/7290043
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231933/7290043

Comment: Try using [BluetoothManager.getAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager#getAdapter())

Comment: @YeasinSheikh After doing that `final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getAdapter();
return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();`
 got this error now `error: cannot find symbol
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getAdapter();
 symbol:   method getAdapter()
location: class BluetoothAdapter`

Answer (score -1):

I added @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") right above the function and that worked for me.

Comment: That warning is there for a reason. The function might not be supported in the future